# using array[] within the slice method to target items to be removed

Tags: javascript, indexing, slice

Using `slice(foo[0], [array.length - 1] )` doesn't seem to slice of the first item, but the last one is removed from the array.

Just messing around with codecademy and I get how slice() method works, it just doesn't work as I thought it might with indices.

`const groceryList = ['orange juice', 'bananas', 'coffee beans', 'brown rice', 'pasta', 'coconut oil', 'plantains'];`

`const newGroceryList = ['avocados', 'kitty litter', 'milk'];`

```
console.log(theNewest.slice(theNewest[0], [theNewest.length - 1]))

console.log(theNewest[0])
```

I expected the array to exclude orange juice and milk, but orange juice remains in the array. Milk has been sliced off so it seems you can use arr.length - 1 to target the last item in the array. Yes, I know you can use pop() to do the same thing, but I'm just playing around to see what works and what doesn't. It also appears that you can't use arr[] anywhere else in the slice() method except for targeting the last item.

Can anyone tell me what is going on under the js covers?

Comment: You do not have `orange juice` in the array. The arguments provided to `slice` should be *integers*, not arrays. Best to read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for a method before wondering why it isn't working

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Snow. I think you may have not understood exactly what I was asking, but now that I look again at what I wrote, it wasn't too clear.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in strings, not integers, as parameters of the `slice` method. Change the first parameter to `0` and the last parameter to `theNewest.length - 1` (no brackets) and check the result.

Comment: It seems to work with or without the brackets. And I know passing in 1 will slice off the first item. 

I also know you have to pass in integers. ```theNewest.length -1``` appears to work as an integer, so I thought arr[0] would pass as an integer as well.

Comment: The result of `theNewest.length - 1` is an integer. The result of `[theNewest.length - 1]` is an array with one value, in this case, a string.

Comment: My question was poorly worded. I guess I was really asking why if ```theNewest.length -1``` passes as in integer, why doesn't arr[0] act as one as well.

Comment: What your call translates to is something like `theNewest.slice('firststring','laststring')` which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: so theNewest.length -1 passes as an integer, but theNewest[0] doesn't? I think I understand because the result of theNewest[0] isn't 0, it's a string, right? For some reason I was equating theNewest[0] with its index in the array, not the value. Thanks for you great feedback.

Comment: So playing around and having fun ```console.log(theNewest.slice(theNewest.length-theNewest.length + 1, theNewest.length -1))``` actually slices off the first and last items. I know no one would do this, I'm just experimenting.

Comment: No problem. The main thing you have to pay attention to is when you are and are not using brackets. theNewest.length +/1 will always be an int. When you wrap it in brackets, you are now referencing an array with an int inside of it. The same thing occurs when you reference 0 or any other number.